# How send string value from activity to adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-adapter

My project has one `activity` named `ResultActivity.java` and an `adapter` named `VoyageAdapter.java`. There is one `string` value in `ResultActivity`, and I want to send this `string` to `VoyageAdapter.java`. How to do this?

ResultActivity.java

```
public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private String fBus;

 }
```

I want to send and use `string` in this part of `VoyageAdapter.java`

VoyageAdapter.java

```
 public class VoyageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VoyageAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    @Override
public VoyageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_voyage_view_bus, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);

}}
```

MyBaseVoyageFragment.java

```
public abstract class MyBaseVoyageFragment extends Fragment {
protected String owner; 
protected View fragmentView; 
protected String fBus;
protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView; 
protected VoyageAdapter voyageAdapter; 
protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
protected ArrayList<Voyage> voyageList;
protected View errorView;
public String BROADCAST_TAG = "com.bss.voyage";
protected int direction = MyConstants.DIRECTION_GOING;
ParseIntentDataAndLoadVoyagesAdapter 
parseIntentDataAndLoadVoyagesAdapter;

protected void init(String owner, int direction) {
    mRecyclerView = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    this.owner = owner;
}

void loadVoyagesToAdapter() {
    if (voyageAdapter == null) {
        voyageAdapter = new VoyageAdapter(getActivity(), voyageList, fBus, mRecyclerView);
        fBus="none";
        Log.v(fBus, "FRAGMENT BUS");
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(voyageAdapter);
    } else {
        voyageAdapter.updateList(voyageList); // sonraki güne geçtiğimde yeni bir voyageadapter oluşturmuyorum.
    }
    if (voyageList.size() < 1 ) { 
        setErrorView(MyConstants.ERROR_NO_VOYAGE);
    }
}

private class ParseIntentDataAndLoadVoyagesAdapter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Intent intent;
    public ParseIntentDataAndLoadVoyagesAdapter(Intent intent) {
        this.intent = intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (isCancelled()) return "";
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(intent.getStringExtra("data"));
            voyageList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
          voyageList.add(Voyage.setJsonToClass(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i), direction, owner));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("getIntent", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

In your adapter make one constructor with a string value.

```
public class VoyageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VoyageAdapter.ViewHolder> {
 private String fBus;

    public VoyageAdapter (Context _context, List<Voyage> _voyageList,RecyclerView recyclerView,String fBus) {
     this.context = _context; 
     this.voyageList = _voyageList;
     this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
     this.fBus= fBus;
  }

}
```

Comment: I have already this code :  `public VoyageAdapter(Context _context, List<Voyage> _voyageList,RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        this.context = _context;
        this.voyageList = _voyageList;
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;` Should I inside of it or can I make other and use it?

Comment: @Skullaykutzz then add just one more string argument to this constructor and its done.

Comment: I did like that. But it comes `null` now in `this.fBus`.

Comment: The problem that I have another class that is `baseFragment` for this adapter. It comes `null` to this class. So, and then I get `null` in adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create public method in your adapter and call it to set String value (like any other setter)

Also, if this String value is determined before creating adapter, you can set it through the adapter's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you have two simple option first make a setter for that string in adapter and call that setter from your activity or put that value in your constructor that depends on your String value is determined before creating adapter or after that

Answer (score 0):

you should add in constructor

```
   String test="";
   OrdersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<OrdersModel> ordersList,String test) {
    this.test=test;
   }

   and create adapter like this:
   ordersAdapter = new OrdersAdapter(this, filterOrdersList,"test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a very simple to pass a string value from activity to adapter. create adapter class parameterized constructor to pass string value

**Like this:**

**MainActivity**

```
    String myValue="User Name";
    TodayAdapter todayAdapter = new TodayAdapter(MainActivity.this,myValue);
myRecyler.setAdapter(todayAdapter);
```

**TodayAdapter.Java**

```
Context context;
String dataValue;

    public TodayAdapter(Context context, String dataValue) {
            this.context = context;
            this.dataValue = dataValue;

        }
```